# gulp plugin gulp-ruby-sass not compiling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass, gulp, gulp-ruby-sass

Gulp plugin **gulp-ruby-sass**(https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-ruby-sass) giving not compiling, the error message in terminal coming like this

> Error: must provide pattern

Here is the **gulpfile.js** details

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
  uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass');

    gulp.task('styles', function (argument) {
        gulp.src('sass/app.scss')
            .pipe(sass())
            .pipe(gulp.dest('css/'));
    });
```

Answer (score 17):

The gulp-ruby-sass syntax has been changed:

```
instead of:                          it is now:

gulp.task('styles', function (){     gulp.task('styles', function (){
    gulp.src('sass/app.scss')            return 
        .pipe(sass())                        sass('sass/app.scss')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css/')              .pipe(gulp.dest('css/')
    ;                                    ;
});                                  });
```

Please check it out and mark your problem as solved.

Comment: ok, what if I want to run sass after some other plugin? so it is not the first method used in pipeline

Answer (score 6):

The [official gulp-ruby-sass documentation](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-ruby-sass) says it should be done like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass');    

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return sass('source/file.scss')
    .on('error', sass.logError)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('result'));
});
```

Comment: I have already  got that solution but still I am afraid why the code `gulp.src('sass/app.scss')` doesn't work. because most of the tutorials are working with this code :( 

example:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cg7lwX0u-U0 , https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NkomAUQxYr8

Comment: The sass function works in a different way. It expects a path 'pattern' argument. That is why you get the error. 
Why isn't the example code working for you? What is it you want to achieve that isn't working out for you with the official example?

Answer (score 2):

> Install **libsass** because it runs much faster than ruby sass ,
>   it works with node

```
npm install gulp-sass --save-dev`
```

> Install **gulp load plugins** because it does so much and loads
>   plugins from your json and you dont need to declare in your gulpfile
>   (carefull how many you use because if you load too many it hinders
>   performance)

```
npm install --save-dev gulp-load-plugins
```

---

```
 var gulp = require('gulp'),
      $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')({
        pattern: ['gulp-*', 'gulp.*'],
        replaceString: /\bgulp[\-.]/,
        lazy: true,
        camelize: true
      });

gulp.task('libsass', function () {
      gulp.src('sass/app.scss')
          .pipe($.sass({errLogToConsole: true}))
          .pipe($.autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
            cascade: false
           }))
          .pipe($.sourcemaps.write('app/css/map'))
          .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
  });
```