# Gulp compile .scss but there is no output

Tags: gulp

I want to compile my scss file using gulp but it doesn't output anything. Here is my task:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'), 
    sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass');

gulp.task('styles', function(){
    return
        gulp.src('scss/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css/'));
    });
```

When I run, everything works fine but my css folder is empty.

[image: output]

Has anyone encountered the same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit of [potential semi-colon insertion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2846283/419956) (you should read your code as if there was a semi-colon after `return`, i.e. you should not let it float on its own on one line), and a bit of [different `gulp-ruby-sass` syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33083374/419956), perhaps? Here's what works for me:

```
"use strict";

var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass');

gulp.task('default', [], function() {
  return sass('scss/*.scss')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css/style.css'));
});
```